# Double (chess like) timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I am thinking about making an android app to support a game of mine, and I can't find info on how to do it. Here is an app explanation:

The app should have two timers (both set for x minutes). When first player starts his turn (by a button click) his time starts running out. when first player makes his move, he should click his time to stop it, and player two starts his turn.

**NOW, the problem I can't find a solution for - When player one takes his turn, time that he loses should pass to the other player's timer.**

*Example: Both players start with a 5 minute timer. If player one takes 30 second for his turn, his time should go down to 04:30, at which time he clicked on his timer. During that time, for each second he lost, the other player gained time on his timer, so at the beginning of his turn, his time is 05:30. The time goes back and forth, and the player whose timer runs out loses the game.*

Any idea how to do this?

I am still stuck to the idea on how to make it, so I have no code to share.

Thank you all for your answers, and effort in helping me, if you have a question I haven't covered, I will gladly answer it.

Comment: I see bad rep, and no comment... Is the question unclear, or is it something else? Help me understand, so that I can be better next time.

Comment: Evo povećao ti rep, pa ću sad pokušati da ti i pomognem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to instantiate class of `CountDownTimer` everytime you click on button.

For reference check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

You have two parameters `long millisInFuture`, `long countDownInterval`

Before you start, you will need to create two global variables one for first player, and one for second player like this:

```
long firstPlayerRemainingTime  = 5 * 60 * 1000; // start time 5 minutes 
long secondPlayerRemainingTime = 5 * 60 * 1000; 
long limitedTime               = 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
```

Now we have came to the most important part and that is logic inside `onClickListener` method

I don't know if there are two buttons or one, but I will go with two buttons:

```
btnFirstPlayer.setTag(1); // start timer
btnFirstPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         if (btnFirstPlayer.getTag() == 1) {
             startTimer();
         } else {
             stopTimer();
         }
    }); 

private void startTimer() {
    long startTime = firstPlayerRemainingTime;

    btnFirstPlayer.setTag(2); // stop timer
    btnFirstPlayer.setText("Stop");

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(firstPlayerRemainingTime, 1000) {
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               firstPlayerRemainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
               tvPlayerOneTimer.setText("" + firstPlayerRemainingTime / 1000)

               // Here you would like to check if 30 seconds has passed
               if ((startTime / 1000) - (limitedTime / 1000) 
                            == (firstPlayerRemainingTime / 1000)) {
                   stopTimer();
               }

               // Here you would like to increase the time of the second player
               secondPlayerRemainingTime = ++1000; 
           }

           public void onFinish() {
               mTextField.setText("done!");
           }

           }.start();
     }
}

private void stopTimer() {
    btnFirstPlayer.setTag(1);
    btnFirstPlayer.setText("Start");
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();

    // I guess here starts second player move

}
```

The same logic would go for second player. Let me know if this helped you or if I need to explain anything.

Comment: OK, setTag is use to start or stop timer. that helps a lot. 
I will try it out, and see if I can make it work, with some adjustments. If I run into some problems, that I can't debug, I'll ask you about it.